# UIElement vs FrameworkElement

Tags: wpf, frameworkelement, uielement

I am unclear about when you would use a `UIElement` as opposed to a `FrameworkElement`, and why is there a `FrameworkElement` class at at all. Essentially, what is the extra functionality that a `FrameworkElement` provides as opposed to `UIElement`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIELement vs Frameworkelement in WPF/Silverlight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956880/uielement-vs-frameworkelement-in-wpf-silverlight)

Comment: @mihajlv: The fact that the answer on that question may be wrong has nothing to do with whether it is a duplicate or not.

Comment: @mihajlv: Also binding has nothing to do with the dispatcher...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never inherit from `UIElement` (no class besides `FrameworkElement` does), among other properties it has no `DataContext`, whose lack can land you in some troubles.

Comment: so just to be clear UIElement provides none of the layout, data binding, styling, templates, and resources.

Comment: @H.B, how come UIElement have Measure and Arrange methods if it does not participate in layout?

Comment: @EmperorAiman: The claim about it not participating in layout is presumably inaccurate, it seems to have some base capabilities but no concrete implementation and no way to adjust the size easily (as all those properties are missing). I don't know the reasoning between the separation of `UIElement` and `FrameworkElement` but just looking at what classes exist it stands to reason that one wants to use `FrameworkElement`.