# Why does custom FrameworkElement not show children?

Tags: c#, wpf

I created program to check ability of `FrameworkElement` to contain `TextBox`.

```
namespace MyControls
{
    public class FooButton : FrameworkElement
    {
        public FooButton()
        {
            Width = 100;
            Height = 100;
            VisualCollection = new VisualCollection(this);
            VisualCollection.Add(new TextBox() { Text = "Meows" });
        }
        protected override int VisualChildrenCount => VisualCollection.Count;
        protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index) => VisualCollection[index];
        public VisualCollection VisualCollection { get; }
    }
}
namespace bitmap_test_example
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is XAML file for program:

```
<Window x:Class="bitmap_test_example.MainWindow"
        xmlns:MyControls = "clr-namespace:MyControls" 
        ......
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <DockPanel>
        <MyControls:FooButton></MyControls:FooButton>
        <Button>yeah</Button>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

But unfortunately program does not show `TextBox`. (By the way I checked visual tree, `TextBox` is indeed contained within custom `FooButton`)What's the problem with code? Maybe additional methods should be redefined for `FrameworkElement`? [image]

Comment: Can you try naming the DockPanel and add the textbox to its children?

Comment: @Emanuele I want to use exactly subclass of `FrameworkElement`. In near future `FooButton` will contain own rendering logic

Comment: The lowest class to use should be [Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.control) class: it has control template, which can be customized. Stripping this away will defeat the huge benefit of WPF - customization. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5956880/1997232).

Comment: @Sinatr the original problem was I missed layout logic. FrameworkElement is also good choice for customization

Comment: "*FrameworkElement is also good choice for customization*" - not at all in any general way.

Comment: @Clemens I agree with you. Just to clarify - I am just porting application written from qt. It originally contained widget with fully custom rendering logic, custom events, custom hit test logic, custom selection etc. That's why I decided to use lightweight object to represent it (FrameworkElement class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implement the `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride` methods of your custom element. The implementations should measure and arrange the visual children, e.g.:

```
public class FooButton : FrameworkElement
{
    private readonly UIElement _child = new TextBox() { Text = "Meows" };

    public FooButton()
    {
        AddVisualChild(_child);
    }

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount => 1;

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index) => index == 0 ? 
        _child : throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        _child.Measure(availableSize);
        return _child.DesiredSize;

    }
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        _child.Arrange(new Rect(finalSize));
        return finalSize;
    }
}
```